# Can I rotate strings with string.format() or any other function in c#?

Tags: .net, html, css, asp.net-mvc-2, format

I am trying to rotate a string 90' and displa it vertically on a graph instead of displaying it in the normal horizontal fashion.I am actually using this on a web application (asp.net mvc 2 website) and not a console or other project .. Is there any built in function or method I can use to achieve that ?

Comment: Where do you want to display it? Forms? Excel? Or what?

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, console?

Comment: string.Format just substitutes tokens to make a new string. To discuss layout (rotation etc) you would have to be very explicit about what UI tool you are using

Comment: What technology do you use ? ASP, WinForms, WPF ?

Comment: In the context of HTML, this is probably a CSS question. Unless you are using a PNG/etc generating tool... Are you?

Comment: no i am not using png/etc generating tool..yea sorry about that silly question..didnt give it much thought before actually posting it..will try to find css way..unfortunately..its flash graph(.swf) so i dont know if i could use css with it..i will work something thx all for your help..

Comment: @Misnomer: sounds like this is flash specific and actually has nothing to do with .net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that has control of the display of a string is the item actually displaying it.  Examples are label and textbox controls, graphing controls, etc

The `String` class itself has no knowledge of what you are going to do with this.

**UPDATE**
Based on the question update and comments: This is flash specific and has nothing at all to do with .net.  You'll need to modify the SWF to display the content at the rotation you want.

Answer (score 1):

How is the string being displayed? `string.Format` is for altering the textual representation of an object (token substitution, formatting of numbers and dates, etc.); it doesn't actually do anything visual (screen location, font, size, orientation, etc.).

If you're drawing the strings yourself with a `Graphics` object, take a look at the overloads for [`DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) that take a [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.aspx) object.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use CSS to do this. Here's a tutorial (be aware it can be very browser specific)

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Answer (score 0):

String.Format() only handles the textual aspect...not the styling (location, font, etc.) of the string being displayed.

Since you mention that this is an ASP.NET MVC 2 application, I would suggest using CSS to rotate your text. Here's a good tutorial on how to implement rotation in a cross-browser manner:

[Text Rotation with CSS - Snook.ca](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation)

Answer (score 0):

It is presentation. C# **string** has nothing to do to it. Use [CSS](http://scottgale.com/blog/css-vertical-text/2010/03/01/) or JavaScript to do this.